# Elasticsearch _bulk returns empty dict

Tags: elasticsearch, python-2.x, elasticsearch-py

I have a strange behavior on my ES7.8 cluster, when inserting data using [elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.10.1/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk) it will say this strange error:

```
  File "./lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 193, in streaming_bulk
    raise_on_error, *args, **kwargs)
  File "./lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 124, in _process_bulk_chunk
    for data, (op_type, item) in zip(bulk_data, map(methodcaller('popitem'), resp['items'])):
KeyError: u'items'
```

To debug this, I added a line to  [`perform_request`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/f4447bf996bdee47a0eb4c736bd39dea20a4486e/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py#L220) before `return` like this:

```
def perform_request(...):
    print(response.status, response.getheaders(), raw_data)
    return response.status, response.getheaders(), raw_data
```

in logs it shows:

```
200 HTTPHeaderDict({'content-length': '2', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}) {}
```

This looks really messed up. When carefully compare the input and actual ES docs, I find that there's 50% chance the data was successfully written into the index and the other 50% fails.

Why does the ES7.8 cluster return an empty response and breaks everything downwards? How I can further debug this?

Comment: Can you show your full Python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's my own stupidity. I specified `filter_path=['hits.hits._id'])` parameter all the way down during bulk request.

Thanks for the tip @Val.